# React native dynamic flatlist height

Tags: react-native

I have a `FlatList` that has 2 potential heights on a screen depending on what is being shown. There are top and bottom bars that show by default and when the `FlatList` is scrolled down, the bars are hidden and the `FlatList` expands to take up the full screen.

The problem is when the `FlatList` shifts between the 2 different heights, the content inside will shift slightly. I have already figured out that I need to apply a scroll offset of the height of the top bar (54), however i'm having issues doing that.

```
const [scrollOffset, setScrollOffset] = useState(0);
const [scrollDir, setScrollDir] = useState("neutral");
<FlatList ...
onScroll={(event) => {
      const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height - SAFE_AREA_INSETS.top - SAFE_AREA_INSETS.bottom;
      const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
      const diff = currentOffset - (scrollOffset || 0);

      if (Math.abs(diff) < 3 || currentOffset < 0 || currentOffset > (event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height - screenHeight)) {
          setScrollDir("neutral");
      }
      else if (diff < 0 && currentOffset <= (event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height - screenHeight)) {
          // Top and bottom bars are shown and flatlist height is adjusted ...

          if(scrollDir !== 'up') {
               flatlistRef.current.scrollToOffset({ animated:false, offset:currentOffset + 54 }); // Not working as intended
          }
          setScrollDir('up');
      }
      else {
          // Top and bottom bars are hidden and flatlist height is adjusted ...

          if(scrollDir !== 'down') {
             flatlistRef.current.scrollToOffset({ animated:false, offset:currentOffset - 54 }); // Not working as intended
          }
          setScrollDir('down');
      }
      setScrollOffset(currentOffset);
}}
```

The `scrollToOffset` method seems to trigger `onScroll` to think its going in the opposite direction which causes oscillations, which from the code makes sense. Any ideas to make this work correctly?

Edit:
Here is a [link to a video of this happening](https://adambeer.ca/RPReplay-Final1631199809.MOV)
When I scroll up/down to unhide/hide the top and bottom bar, you'll see the content in the center jump up/down. It makes sense why this is happening, the height of the center content changes which causes the jump. I want the content to stay scrolled in the same position when changing the height.

Comment: Can you show us the problematic part in the video?

Comment: @hongdeveloper I have updated the question with a video of what is happening.